# Error returning jFuzzyLogic result as double value

Tags: java, fuzzy-logic, jfuzzylogic

I want to return the result of the fuzzy logic as a double to be used by another class.
I am using the following java code:

public class MyFuzzyClass {

```
public double getFuzzy() {
    String fileName = "tipper.fcl";  //we have to add this file
    FIS fis = FIS.load(fileName,true);

    if( fis == null ) { // Error while loading?
        System.err.println("Can't load file: '" + fileName + "'");
        return;
    }

    // show rule set
    FunctionBlock functionBlock = fis.getFunctionBlock(null);

    JFuzzyChart.get().chart(functionBlock);

    // set inputs
    functionBlock.setVariable("service", 3);
    functionBlock.setVariable("food", 7);

    // evaluate
    functionBlock.evaluate();

    Variable tip = functionBlock.getVariable("tip");
    Double tip_new = tip.getValue(); 
    System.out.println("Tip:" + functionBlock.getVariable("tip").getValue());
    return tip_new;

}
```

}

But I got an error in this return statement:

```
if( fis == null ) { // Error while loading?
        System.err.println("Can't load file: '" + fileName + "'");
        return;
    }
```

How can I solve this error??

Comment: Try using full path of the 'tipper.fcl'

Comment: thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: it is solved now. the problem was the path.